# Multiple Inheritance in Java . Assigning priority via extends order

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

[Oracle Java Tutorials, Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html):

> One reason why the Java programming language does not permit you to extend more than one class is to avoid the issues of multiple inheritance of state, which is the ability to inherit fields from multiple classes. For example, suppose that you are able to define a new class that extends multiple classes. When you create an object by instantiating that class, that object will inherit fields from all of the class's superclasses. What if methods or constructors from different superclasses instantiate the same field?

Couldn't this problem be easily solved by **assigning priorities** to all the classes a subclass extends?

```
class A extends B,C,D
{

}
```

Let us assume that priority was assigned in the **ascending order in which they are mentioned** in declaration of subclass  .

Then priority of B < priority of C < priority of D . So if there is any state or behaviour common to any of these classes B ,C or D then priority decides what should be inherited and what should be hided.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a specific question about code you're writing, or a general conversation about a recommendation you'd like to make to the Java language specifications?

Comment: @David It is not specific to any code . I just want to know why java guys designed java in the way it is . I also want to know what are the complications involved in the approach I suggested. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid open-ended conversations like this are not well-suited to Stack Overflow.  To learn more about this community and what we do, you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  There are chat rooms available for general discussions among community contributors, it's possible this may be suitable in one of those.

Comment: They've allowed for multiple inheritance of type (interfaces), behavior (defaulted methods), but _not_ state. Multiple inheritance of state introduces [the diamond problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) to class state, something more difficult to compensate for and much more likely to arise as an issue. (Solving this problem for behavior is a simple matter of implementing the method in `D`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, roughly speaking, this how Scala supports extending a class with multiple *Traits*

"priorities" are determined based on a [linearization equation](https://www.aptsoftware.com/scala-linearization-technique-to-avoid-multiple-inheritance/), similar to what you mentioned so there is no ambiguity.